# How can I limit a "Run Script" build phase to my release configuration?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-build-settings

I have a shell script that I would like to run at the end of my target's build phase. However, I would like this script to only run when I build with the **release** configuration. How can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 342, accepted):

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
  echo Do something really release-like
fi
```

The script will run at the end of every configuration, but it won't do anything in this case unless the configuration is Release (assuming everything it does is contained within the test block).

Comment: I just discovered it does not work with multi-worded configuration names. It works with "Release" but does not with "Internal Beta".

Comment: @Hedin - that is just bash; if you have multi-word variable, you need to surround the variable in quotes. So ${CONFIGURATION} becomes "${CONFIGURATION}". I'll update the answer to include that.

Comment: So I tried this with a script that uploads to crittercism the dysm file.  Something's not working and xcode gets stuck on the phase when I add the wrapper of the "if". Any ideas?  if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Hockey Distribution" ]; then
APP_ID="xxxxxxxx"
API_KEY="xxxxxxxxx"
source ${SRCROOT}/GlideiPhone/Vendor/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh
fi

Comment: I have 'Debug', 'Release' (for Instruments), 'Ad Hoc' and 'App Store' configs (with different code signing), so I changed it for `if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" != "Debug" ]; then...`.

Comment: For the if condition i want to use a #define TRUE/FALSE stored in the .pch file.. how would i reference it in the script code?

Comment: @skyline75489 : Bash uses `=` and `==` interchangeably.

Comment: Can this same thing be accomplished with pre-processor flags?

Comment: This snippet was not working. I needed to change the "=="
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]

Comment: if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]; then ... works for me in Xcode 14

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way to do this, is checking the "Run script only when installing" checkbox. 
[image]

Comment: +1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913199/xcode-run-script-build-phase-run-script-only-when-installing-option

Comment: "Debug-installing on a real device (build & run from Xcode) does not count as "installing". The run script only runs when archiving (tested with Xcode 9)." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913199/xcode-run-script-build-phase-run-script-only-when-installing-option#comment80890236_21917496

Comment: It won't work if you want to build your app in `Release` configuration without archiving it. The question was explicitly about `Release` configuration.