# Xcode Run script Build Phase "run script only when installing" option

Tags: xcode

There is a "run script only when installing" option in Xcode Run script Build Phase, I am not able to find documentation on this.  What does it do?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

With **Run script only when installing** checked, the script only runs when do Product Archive.

Comment: Not when building/installing on a device?  (That is: `CMD-B` build & run to a physical device (not sim) with the device plugged in.  Does that not count as "when installing" for this switch?)

Comment: Debug-installing on a real device (build & run from Xcode) does not count as "installing". The run script only runs when archiving (tested with Xcode 9).

Comment: Actually this is only partially correct. It depends on the DEPLOYMENT_PROCESSING setting. I'm basing this from running this on Xcode 10. It appears that when you archive, DEPLOYMENT_PROCESSING is set to YES and overrides the setting for the configuration. I've confirmed this through building and seeing the settings in the output since I have "Show environment variables in build log" set to on.

Comment: From @Ericg the flag is `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING`. In looking at the Xcode 14 flags it confirms that is what is used.

Answer (score 21):

In the Xcode Build System Guide (Xcode 3.2.x), it says:

> **Run script only when installing.** Runs the script only during install builds, that is, when using the install option of xcodebuild or when the build settings Deployment Location (DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION) and Deployment Postprocessing (DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING) are on.

Comment: When you need / want to...? I would suggest reading the documentation on DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION, DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING, & TARGET_BUILD_DIR.

Comment: Read it, but what situations do people use them for?

Comment: Re: when would you want to use this: I use this flag on scripts that increment the build number, so that it only happens on builds I archive to send out to beta testers (and not every single time I run the app)

Comment: Or when uploading symbol files to firebase or crashlytics. No need to upload that on every single debug build.

Comment: Actually Fabric tells that symbol files should be uploaded every build. There are better way to configurate the uploading of dSYM. https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/118559-can-i-make-the-dsym-uploading-only-on-release-buil