# Xcode build configuration based app transport layer security

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, app-transport-security

I have 2 build configurations as usual. `Debug`,`Adhoc`,`Release`. I want to disable iOS App transport layer security for `Debug` configuration. So basically I want to have changes in Info.plist that are different for each configuration. How Could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a build script to inject details into the plist. This would use a setup like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614017/how-can-i-limit-a-run-script-build-phase-to-my-release-configuration) to determine the build type and would use `PlistBuddy` to edit the plist. This is a very flexible but relatively complex solution, it allows you very fine grained control.

The other answer about using multiple different plist files is a lot simpler but requires that you maintain multiple copies of the plist and ensure that they are updated appropriately.

Comment: Both answers are valid. I will accept this as I ended up using this approach. This also explains the differences between two. I will add some code I used below.

Answer (score 3):

Create a different plist file for the debug version and use it. This would serve your purpose I am sure.[image]

Comment: This works. I wish we cud have more elegant solution. I tried to set user defined setting. And Use that to set Allow Arbitrary Load option. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with to achieve this.

Added a run script with following.

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]; then
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :NSAppTransportSecurity:NSAllowsArbitraryLoads YES" ProjectName/Info.plist
fi
```